# How to implement voice keyword recognition in my android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Im building a personal app to use in my car, I want to control some apps from this service/app using only voice like Google does with "Ok google" to trigger the service. So far I was able to use the android built in speechRecognizer to start creating my app, but I still nned to use a button to start listen for a task, and then on the onResults use the 'if (match.toLowerCase().contains("What was said"))' to do something. Can I implement the "Ok google" to trigger my app voice recognition with a custom keyword?

I tried to use pocketsphinx demo from github but I think its a little to old, had a lot of issues with version wasted hours testing to see if I could make it work but I gave up.

Comment: See: https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/voice/voice_interaction_guide/app_development and https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/voice/voice_interaction_guide/app_development#hotwords but the permissions for true "wake word" are system level so probably with a custom ROM.